# Some of my walnut trees have double trunks. Is it safe and wise to remove one?

Tags: fruit-trees, pruning, walnut

I have bought an orchard which has some walnut that are about 10 years old. These walnuts have been never pruned. Some of them have two or three trunks. Is it safe or wise to remove one of them?
[image: walnut tree double trunk]

Can I remove left and right branch from below tree? or they are too thick to be removed.
[image: walnut tree that have been never pruned]

Comment: Often low branching as shown , is desirable for harvesting ; many nuts are low and do not need ladders. Commercial growing where a machine shakes the trees, use single trunks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends, for what reason do you want to remove them? If it's for aesthetic reasons - to give them a "classic tree" shape with a clear stem - then that is just up to you. Just proceed carefully and remove the material over the course of two or three years, if it's a substantial proportion of the whole plant to avoid shock.

If you want to maintain this as a productive orchard then I doubt it will be beneficial to prune out those branches and I suspect they may in fact be a deliberate result of formative pruning from the first few years of these trees lives. If you want to keep these trees as productive as possible then I suggest looking up specific advice for pruning walnut trees, in orchards specifically.

All the normal advice for pruning applies: start by removing the three D's: Dead, Diseased, and Damaged branches. Then remove any branches that are crossing each other and those that are growing inwards.